# Registration form for extended user raises error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I've extended a User to be able to store more attributes. Now, I'm trying to create a registration form for this `UserProfile`. How to create form which creates a `UserProfile` with all attributes, requirements etc? And make `first_name`,`last_name` required.

There is very similar question without answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050266/create-registration-form-for-extended-user-model-in-django-1-8)

I've tried this but with no success:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self,commit = True):
        user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.telephone = self.cleaned_data['telephone']


        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Getting this error:

```
    class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages\venv\
lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 257, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for Use
rProfile
```

**HERE IS A PART OF MODELS AND ADMIN:**

**MODELS.PY:**

```
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # ATRIBUTY KTORE BUDE MAT KAZDY
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
            ('coincidence',u'It was coincidence'),
            ('relative_or_friends','From my relatives or friends'),
            )
    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True)

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single','Single'),
        ('married','Married'),
        ('separated','Separated'),
        ('divorced','Divorced'),
        ('widowed','Widowed'),
    )
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name,self.surname)

def create_profile_user_callback(sender,instance, **kwargs):
    profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_profile_user_callback, User)
```

**ADMIN.PY:**

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'User_Profile'

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form contains no attribute username, yet below Meta, there is username included. Try adding username on your forms field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach you have of having a one-to-one to User model on your profile is a good one. The only problem is how you have created your forms. Make them separate. Something like this:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('extra_field1', 'extra_field2')
```

In the view, you are able to save the user, get the pk and add it as foreign key to profile. Have a look at [Vitors post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) for some good clues. There is also the bit about using post-save signals to make sure you alway have a profile.